# How to replace a char * in C?

Tags: c

I am currently writing a shell for school purposes and I have the problem that if I write the command "history", the "exit" command afterwards doesn't work. If you could help me I would be very happy.
Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>


#define MAX_INPUT 256

static char cwd[100];

void myprintf(char *text) {
    text != NULL ?
    printf("%s@rash:%s: %s\n", getenv("USER"), getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)), text) :
    printf("%s@rash:%s: ", getenv("USER"), getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)));
}

void errprintf(char *text) {
    myprintf(NULL);
    printf("Couldn't run %s\n", text);
}

static char *argv[256];
static int argc;
static int pid = 0;

FILE *fhistory;

void parseInput(char *input) {
    input = strtok(input, "\n");
    for (argc = 0; argc < MAX_INPUT; argc++) {
        argv[argc] = NULL;
    }
    argc = 0;
    fprintf(fhistory, "%s\n", input);
    char *param = strtok(input, " ");
    while (param) {
        argv[argc++] = param;
        param = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

void signalHandler(int sign) {
    switch (sign) {
        case SIGINT: {
            if (pid != 0) {
                kill(pid, SIGKILL);
                pid = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
        case SIGCHLD: {
            if (pid != 0) {
                kill(pid, SIGKILL);
                pid = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

int programs() {
    if (!strcmp(argv[0], "exit")) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!strcmp(argv[0], "cd")) {
        chdir(argv[1] == NULL ? getenv("HOME") : argv[1]);
    } else {
        pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
            case -1: {
                myprintf("Erectile Dysfunction!");
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                if (!strcmp(argv[0], "history")) {
                    system("cat .rash_history.txt");
                } else {
                    execvp(argv[0], argv);
                    errprintf(argv[0]);
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
                signal(SIGCHLD, signalHandler);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    char *input = NULL;
    myprintf("Welcome to rash!");
    fhistory = fopen(".rash_history.txt", "a");
    while (input != NULL ? strncmp(input, "exit", strlen(input)) != 0 : 1) {
        myprintf(NULL);
        input = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_INPUT);
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_INPUT; j++) {
            input[j] = '\0';
        }
        fgets(input, MAX_INPUT, stdin);
        parseInput(input);
        if (*(input) != '\n') {
            programs();
        }
    }
    fclose(fhistory);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I don't see any call to `programs()`.

Comment: Sorry, accidently deleted it, but I added it now

Comment: Your `malloc` call is wrong.  You have an array of `char`, so you want `sizeof(char)`, not `sizeof(char *)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here `while (input != NULL ? strncmp(input, "exit", strlen(input)) != 0 : 1) {`

it would be `strlen("exit")`

Answer (score 0):

1. The "input" variable take value inside your while loop only:

   ```
   fgets(input, MAX_INPUT, stdin);
   parseInput(input);
   ```
2. The parseInput uses strtok function couple times. The strtok modifies the argument string, so it not clear what value it will contains at time you will compare it with "exit".

Try to duplicate "input" string before calling strtok. Try to add debug string at the end of loop to make clear what value is into input string.